# MVC 5 Facebook Publishing Feed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been playing around with the open graph api and more or so with the Publishing part as mentioned here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#publishing

It mentions `For example, to publish a post on behalf of someone, you would make an HTTP POST request as below:` I require the `UserID` and `Access Token`.

So I have been able to get the `Access Token` which doesn't expire and also the `User ID` of the user that has accepted the app to publish content.

However to my failure I am unable to post feed by using the steps mentioned in the above link.

This is a small example I put together to test the HttpPost Request

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FacebookPostResponse(string accessToken)
{

string fbPost = "Hello";

Uri targetUserUri = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/10153688496941651/feed?message=" + fbPost + "&access_token=" + accessToken);

HttpWebRequest post = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUserUri);

HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)post.GetResponse();
var sC = res.StatusCode;
ViewBag.Message = sC;
}
```

The `ActionResult` above returns me a status code of `OK` meaning the request was successful. However when I go to my facebook wall I don't see anything from the app?

When I copy the URL request in a web browser it returns the following:

```
{
  "data": [

  ]
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing incorrect? Anybody have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up your HttpWebRequest instance to use POST http method, the default value is GET
so just add this: 
 `post.Method = "POST";` 
After :

```
HttpWebRequest post = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUserUri);
```